# Excel formula that returns comma separated names based on ID's, the formula should allow for as many IDs as possible

Tags: excel, csv

I need to create a formula which

This is sheet 1, I need formulas in the second column of this sheet which reads the names from sheet [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZeGv.png) and return the names in a comma separated format:
[image].

This is sheet 2 which contains ID's and corresponding names for these ID's in which Sheet [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjvWT.png) reads from:
[image].

I would like to do this without VBA, and make use of excel formulas.

Data:

```
| ID    | Name       |
|-------|------------|
| 8     | apple      |
| 8.1.3 | banana     |
| 8.2   | charlie    |
| 8.3   | delta      |
| 8.4   | echo       |
| 8.5   | foxtrot    |
| 8.5.1 | gamma      |
| 8.5.2 | hello      |
| 8.5.3 | instrument |
| 9     | jump       |
| 9.1.2 | kangaroo   |
```

Answer (score 2):

The following entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I am assuming test string to convert is in `E2` and you enter this in `F2`, you would then drag down.

Credit to @ScottCraner for fixing this.

```
 =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(44),TRUE, IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$12,N(IF({1},MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(E3,CHAR(44), "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"),$A$1:$A$12,0)))),""))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't assume any spaces alongside the delimiter.

Comment: I still only get the first one, even deleting the spaces.

Comment: Aghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: This was what I couldn't ascertain as couldn't test! Back to delete! :sighs:  Already upvoted yours btw @ScottCraner I will be nicking that for later if you don't mind. Seems it doesn't like the Index bit

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you not use index in an array formula to return an array of values? I saw Excel do it for a minute but now refuses to do it!

Comment: I believe @ashleedawg got it to work. I am confused.

Comment: Yes with some round about methods, you need to make an array of the second, or third, criterion.  Match does not return an array.

Comment: I have filterXML producing an array. I then Match on that array using an array formula and all is well. For example, 8, 8.1.3, 8.5 gives me a nice array using an array formula of =IFERROR(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(E2,CHAR(44), "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"),$A$1:$A$12,0),"") I get {2;3;7} back.

Comment: Use this: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(44),TRUE, IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$12,N(IF({1},MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(E3,CHAR(44), "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"),$A$1:$A$12,0)))),""))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Is there anything you can't do with a formula? Mind if I add that in? So frustrating I can't test. Don't know why my Excel 2016 doesn't have it as a function.

Comment: that one works if i DONT trim out the whitespace but not if I do (see comment on other answer)

Comment: @ashleedawg in your photo of the one that worked F2 was missing Bananas.  It was only bringing the first match.

Comment: Thanks to you both. @ScottCraner and AshleeDawg.

Answer (score 2):

Use this as an array formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", " & $A$2:$A$12 & ", ",", "& E2 & ", ")),$B$2:$B$12,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

This formula assumes there is always a comma ***AND*** a space between the numbers. In the lookup.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel.  Earlier versions will require vba or putting the output in separate cells.

[image]

Comment: I just tried your answer and @QHarr's and can't get either to work.  I paste your array formula in F2 and should have a result right?

Comment: This is where it's all supposed to be? or am i missing something? https://i.stack.imgur.com/leM8D.png

Comment: @ashleedawg yes your are missing the lookup value in E2

Comment: ah yes, it works. I didn't realize there was any manual entry going on, i misunderstood the question :)   @Qharr's works fine too now that I know that...and he woulda beat ya to it, if he didn't delete cuz i said i said it didn't work.  oops :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg did you get Qharrs to return multiple?  I can only get it to return the first.

Comment: @ashleedawg then what am I doing wrong becuase I only get one: https://imgur.com/a/LmNsDQ1

Comment: Actually... I just noticed the extra spaces in his result because of the way i imported the sample data (text to columns left spaces this time for some reason)... so i used trim on the sample data and now qharr's only partly works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zz9Z.png

Comment: Because I am splitting on char(44) only, not char(44)&chr(32). If there are spaces then FilterXML needs to know about them.

Comment: Thank you, so using the CONCATENATE function couldn't be possible to get the appropriate results? Asking because I have Excel 2013

Comment: @Royal no it will not work.  The only way to avoid vba in this case is to put the output in different cells, one cell per output.  Then you can concatenate the output cells but that requires knowing before hand how many cells would be possible.